# slicing number Type error slice is not function on javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
TypeError: ((a2 / b2) * 100).slice is not a function
```

```
a2 = parseInt(this.state)|| 0;
b2 = parseInt(this.state) || 0;
let display = <><td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{((a2 / b2) * 100).slice(0, 5)}%</td></>
```

it works without using slice, but I need to slice my number after count (a2/b2)*100, it is because I put slice on wrong location?

Comment: What's the output you expect? If you're trying to get a certain number of decimal places, that's [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Comment: data string, there is an empty or null 'content and number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the aim of trying to slice a number? Slice works on [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) but not on numbers

You can do this if you meant to slice the string representation of the number

```
String((a2 / b2) * 100).slice(0, 5)
```

but I assume you really meant

```
(a2 / b2) * 100).toFixed(2)
```